# Date-fns—omit year if it's current year

Tags: javascript, date

Using the [format function of date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/format), is it possible to omit the year if it is the current year? Is there some format string to enable this?

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns'

const date = new Date('July 4, 2021')

// current year is 2021

format(date, 'format string')
// should output "July 4"

format(date, 'format string')
// should output "July 4, 2020"
```

If there's another date-fns function that does this aside from `format`, that's also fine. I'm assuming though that any such solution will likely use the `format` function since this is, well, formatting the date.

### Alternative solutions

I know it's currently possible to use an `if` statement to do this manually.

```js
const date = new Date('July 4, 2021')
if (date.getFullYear() === (new Date()).getFullYear()) {
    format(date, 'MMM d')
} else {
    format(date, 'MMM d, YYY')
}
```

While this works, I'm more curious if there's a way to format this natively with date-fns.

Comment: If you're using a date library then `new Date('July 4, 2021')` is something of an anathema. Likely the best you can do is something like `format(d, 'MMM d' + (d.getFullYear() == new Date().getFullYear()? '' : ', YYYY'))`.